# Getting length of sentence between tag in BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Am trying to collect some statistics from a website, what am trying to do is extract a `word` and count of neigbour words found within the same tag for example

**Input**

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
   <p class="w50">Operating Temperature (Min.)[°C]</p>
   <p class="w50 upperC">-40</p>
</div>
```

would result into

**TAG 1**

```
Operating , 2 i.e #<Temperature, (Min.)[°C]>
Temperature, 2 i.e #<Operating, (Min.)[°C]>
(Min.)[°C], 2 i.e #<Operating,Temperature>
```

**TAG 2**

```
-40, 0
```

this what I ended up to, but it extracts text as whole

```
url = 'https://www.rohm.com/products/wireless-communication/wireless-lan-modules/bp3580-product#'
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as url:
        page = url.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, features='lxml')

# [print(tag.name) for tag in soup.find_all()]

for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
    script.decompose()  # rip it out

invalid_tags = ['br']

for tag in invalid_tags:
    for match in soup.findAll(tag):
        match.replaceWithChildren()

html = soup.find_all(recursive=False)

for tag in html:
    print(tag.get_text())
```

I tried to with `recursive = True` but the result is duplicated alot

Comment: Could you provide the URL you want to scrap?

Comment: @Yusufsn, added in code snippet

Comment: You said "count of neighbour words found within the same tag". What tag do you mean?

Comment: @Yusufsn, am targeting all tags that contain text directly

Comment: @fadytaher : what is your expected out put can you mentioned.

Comment: To print all specifications? or something else?

Comment: @KunduK, for all **words** in the HTML I want to build a table of  `word, count of neighbour words within the same tag`, please check the sample I provided in the question

Comment: @KunduK simply, I just need to extract each tag content separtely without repitition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not be the result what you have exected for, but at least it gives you a hint. I modified your code a little bit.

```
url = 'https://www.rohm.com/products/wireless-communication/wireless-lan-modules/bp3580-product#'
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as url:
    page = url.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, features='lxml')

for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
    script.decompose()  # rip it out

invalid_tags = ['br']

for tag in invalid_tags:
    for match in soup.findAll(tag):
        match.replaceWithChildren()

html = soup.find_all(recursive=False)

textlist = []
for tag in html:
    text = tag.text.replace("\r","").replace("\t","").split("\n")
    for t in text:
        if t != '':
            textlist.append(t)
for tt in textlist:
    print(tt)
    for ts in tt.split():
        print ("{}, {}".format(ts,len(tt.split())-1))
    print("-----------------------------")
```